# Call factory only on first load

Tags: angularjs, controller, factory

I have this code inside my controller:

```
$scope.customers = [];
$scope.categories = [];

function init() {
   partnersFactory.getPartners(categoryId)
   .then(function(res){
      $scope.partners = res;
   },function(status){
      //err
   })

   partnersFactory.getCategories()
   .then(function(res){
      $scope.categories = res;
   },function(status){
      //err
   })
}
```

What I do need, is to run partnersFactory.getCategories() only once on initial load, and then save it unchanged. What is the best approach to do it so? Using some variables like var initialization = false look not very clean.

**EDIT**
The purpose: I have some data sorted by categories. What am I doing now: if someone clicks on category, I reload the dataset from server, but filter it to the category (server-side). That's why i need to reload data, but not the categories. Am I doing wrong? Maybe it's better to filter it inside angularjs?? (the data on server is not constantly updating).

Comment: Call it in you controller function?

Comment: So everytime you click on a category, you call init()?

Comment: I don't get it, you want to get categories only on init, that's it?   and then user click somewhere and you reload only data, isn't it ?

Comment: Yes, on first load I load categories and all the data. If user clicks on categories, I it just filters the data. Now I'm reloading everything, and dont think its very clever...

Comment: Okay, what you should do is to create a method that load data, another that load categories. On init, you call both those methods. Then put a ng-click on categories that call getData() when the user click on it. Does that sounds answer your question? if so, i'll make a more detailed answer ;)

Comment: yes, no need to get the filtered the data again. you can do it in angular side. how do u want to filter the data ?

Comment: tanou - yes, it looks like the right way)  Kalhano Toress Pamuditha - i have categories array in every data row and want to select the rows, where selecter category is in this array. But there is another problem I need to access specific categories via specific urls, so if someine loads the page via www.mysite.com/category/2, it have to load data (categories and main data), filter it and render everything, and then, if user clicks on other categories, it only filters data...

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
$scope.customers = [];
$scope.categories = null;

function init() {
   partnersFactory.getPartners(categoryId)
   .then(function(res){
      $scope.partners = res;
   },function(status){
  //err
   })

   if($scope.categories == null) {
       partnersFactory.getCategories()
       .then(function(res){
          $scope.categories = res;
       },function(status){
          $scope.categories = [];
       })
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, i've tried that way, but it brings nothing, coz i run the controller every time and reinitialize everything. See my edits to post

Answer (score 1):

putting  `partnersFactory.getCategories()` out side of the `init()` function will only execute one time

so your controller likes to be,

```
$scope.customers = [];
$scope.categories = [];

function init() {
   partnersFactory.getPartners(categoryId)
   .then(function(res){
      $scope.partners = res;
   },function(status){
      //err
   })       
}

partnersFactory.getCategories()
.then(function(res){
    $scope.categories = res;
},function(status){
      //err
})
```

and if you need a clean copy of the `$scope.categories` use `angular.copy()` like below

```
partnersFactory.getCategories()
.then(function(res){
    $scope.categories = res;
    $scope.originalObj = angular.copy($scope.categories); // don't do any changes to $scope.originalObj
},function(status){
      //err
})
```

Answer (score 1):

In your factory you can do it smth like this:

```
.factory('partnersFactory', function($http) {
    var categories = [];

    var getCategories = function() {
       $http.get(...)
          .success(function(data){
             categories = data;
          });
    }
    getCategories();

    return {
        getPartners: function(categoryId) {
           $http.get(...)
              .success(onSuccess)
              .error(onError);
        },
        getCategories: function(){
           return categories;
        }
    };
```

It should cash categories data.

Answer (score 1):

So, what you need is something like that:

in your controller, create 2 methods, one for getting the categories, the other for getting the data:

```
angular.module('yourApp').controller('yourCtrl', ['$scope', 'yourFactory', function ($scope, yourFactory) {

  $scope.initPage = function () {
     $scope.getCat();
     $scope.getData();
  }

  $scope.getCat = function () {
     ...
  }

  $scope.getData = function () {
     ...
  }


  $scope.initPage();
}]);
```

then in your html, on the button/element supposed to reload data, call your method with a ng-click

```
<div>
  <button ng-click="getData"> reload </button>
</div>
```

As you want to sort per categories, you can do something like adding a param to getData(category) to precise by which category you want to filter your data, then in your html

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="cat in categories"> <a ng-click="getData(cat)"> {{ cat.name }} </a> </li>
</ul>
```

hope it help